# Spider Identification in Miami, FL

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

These two spiders were found at the Fairchild Gardens in Miami, FL.

What spiders are these?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to separate this into two questions and include size estimates for both species. Please also consult the "species-identification" tag (click on the tag I added to your post) for more information on how to best ask this kind of question. Thanks! 

Comment: The second one is called the golden silk spider commonly found in forests.

Comment: @JossieCalderon If you are certain about that post it as an answer. It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: @aminabzz Terrible moderating removed it. This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted and converted to a comment last month by AliceD♦

Comment: @AliceD terrible.